# ¿Como sumar columnas en un DataGriedView?

Tags: c#

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto en cual quiero sumar columnas de un datagriedview unicamente he podido sumar la primera columna

```
private void btnResultado_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value);
    double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value);
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = num1 + num2;
}
```

[image: Imagen de Muestra]

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular en cada row deberas iterar cada una usando un `foreach`, algo como esto

```
foreach(var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].Value);
    double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
    row.Cells[4].Value = num1 + num2;
}
```

asi podras tomar el valor de las celdas de cada row y completar la ultima con la suma

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto una función que uso para sumar una columna de cualquier DataGridView, espero te sirva

```
   public static double ObtenerSumaDeColumna(DataGridView dgv, int columna)
   {
        try
        {
            double suma = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                suma = suma + Convert.ToDouble(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[columna].Value);
            }
            return suma;
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```